# schema.parseAsync is not a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, zod

I am trying to perform zod validation in Node.js, but I get an error:

> TypeError: schema.parseAsync is not a function

I tried everything, importing again and all, but can't get over it.

My auth-router.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const authControllers = require("../controllers/auth-controller");
const signupSchema = require("../validator/auth-validator")
const validate = require('../middleware/validate-middleware');

router.route('/').get(authControllers.home);
router.route('/register').post(validate(signupSchema) ,authControllers.register);
router.route('/login').post(authControllers.login);

module.exports = router;
```

My validat-middleware.js:

```
const validate = (schema) => async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log(schema);
        const parsedBody = await schema.parseAsync(req.body);
        req.body = parsedBody;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        // const message = err.error.message;
        res.status(400).json({ message: "Validation Failed" });
    }
};

module.exports = validate;
```

My zod-validation schema:

```
const { z } = require('zod')

const signupSchema = z.object({
    username: z
    .string({ required_error: "Username is required"})
    .trim()
    .min(3, {message: "Username must be at least 3 characters"})
    .max(255, {message: "Username must be less than 255 characters"}),

    email: z
    .string({ required_error: "Email is required"})
    .trim()
    .min(3, {message: "Email must be at least 3 characters"})
    .max(255, {message: "Email must be less than 255 characters"}),

    phone: z
    .string({reportError: "Phone no. is required"})
    .trim()
    .min(10, {message: "Phone no. must be at least 10 characters"})
    .max(20, {message: "Phone no. must be less than 20 characters"}),

    pasword: z
    .string({ required_error: "Password is required"})
    .min(7, {message: "Password must be at least 6 characters"})
    .max(1024, {message: "Password must be less than 1024 characters"}),
})

module.exports = { signupSchema };
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

you need to import it like this:
`const {signupSchema} = require("../validator/auth-validator")`